# modify the part of the OID returned in "oid" and "oid_index" by Python easysnmp module

Tags: python, easysnmp

Python [easysnmp](https://easysnmp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/session_api.html) module returns the SNMP OID in two parts: `oid` and `oid_index`. For example, if I walk the `ipAddressIfIndex.ipv4`(`.1.3.6.1.2.1.4.34.1.3.1` in numerical form) OID:

```
>>> from easysnmp import Session
>>> session = Session(hostname="r1", community='public', version=2, use_long_names=True, use_sprint_value=True)
>>> session.bulkwalk("ipAddressIfIndex.1")
[<SNMPVariable value='9' (oid='.iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.ip.ipAddressTable.ipAddressEntry.ipAddressIfIndex', oid_index='1.4.192.0.2.1', snmp_type='INTEGER')>,

/* rest of the output is removed for brevity */

>>>
```

.. then the `oid` is `.iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.ip.ipAddressTable.ipAddressEntry.ipAddressIfIndex`(or `.1.3.6.1.2.1.4.34.1.3` numerically) and `oid_id` is `1.4.192.0.2.1`. I would like to shift the returned `oid` to right by two so that the `oid_id` would be `192.0.2.1`. Is this possible? I have tried with `session.bulkwalk("ipAddressIfIndex.1.4")`, `session.bulkwalk(("ipAddressIfIndex", "1.4"))`, `session.bulkwalk(".1.3.6.1.2.1.4.34.1.3.1.4")` and used various session parameters like `use_long_names` or `use_enums`, but I'm not able to modify this behavior.

This is obviously not a big issue as I can read the last four fields(for example something like `oid_index.split('.')[-4:]`), but maybe there is a trick to shift the "line" between the `oid` and `oid_index` returned by easysnmp.

Comment: Why do you want to shift `oid_index` right by 2?

Comment: Because last four integers of the `oid_id` is the IPv4 address which I'm interested of. In the example above the IPv4 address would be `192.0.2.1`.

Answer (score -1):

you can use regex to extract you information

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'(?:\d+\.){3}\d+$')
tuple('{}/{}'.format(regex.search(item.oid).group(0), item.value)
      for item in system_items)
```

or you can use **PySNMP**

```
class SNMPVariable(object):
    def __init__(self, value, oid):
       self.value = value 
       self.oid = oid  
#example      
s1 = SNMPVariable('255.255.255.0', 'iso.3.6.1.2.1.4.21.1.11.10.10.2.0')
prtin('{}/{}'.format(regex.search(s1.oid).group(0), s1.value)
```

check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49417978/python-regex-to-extract-ip-and-mask-from-snmp-walk-output)